# Execute a Linux application remotelly from PowerShell

Tags: linux, powershell, ssh, plink, ssh.net

I'm trying to execute a application console command (`cslogin`) on a Linux box from PowerShell. I used the SSH module from [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) to access the Linux server. The following is a snapshot of my script, I'm able to establish the ssh session.

```
Import-Module SSH-Sessions
$user     = "user"
$password = "pass"
$hostname = "192.168.1.X"
C:\plink.exe -ssh -l $username -pw $password $hostname "cslogin"
```

But once the `cslogin` command is executed the script hangs with the following message:

> SEC054 A device has connected to, or disconnected from, a pseudo tty without 
>   authenticating

At this point if I hit the enter key I am able to get the application prompt, which is what I want.  I am trying to understand why does my script hangs and how do I get around this issue.

Comment: This post is similar, might be useful - http://superuser.com/questions/302749/call-putty-plink-to-start-a-remote-ssh-linux-script-with-user-input

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here that isn't better served by using putty?

Answer (score 1):

You only import the `SSH-Sessions` module, without actually using it. You then run PLink, that is not related to SSH.NET at all.

---

Pure SSH.NET solution is like:

```
Import-Module SSH-Sessions
New-SshSession -ComputerName "192.168.1.X" -Username "user" -Password "pass"
Invoke-SshCommand -InvokeOnAll "cslogin"
```

---

Other than that your PLink solution does the same. As it does not work, the SSH.NET solution above won't probably work either.

Your actual problem is that the application (`cslogin`) requires an interactive terminal (TTY). PLink by default does not allocate one. And I believe that SSH.NET does not either. With PLink, you can force TTY using `-t` switch:

```
$user     = "user"
$password = "pass"
$hostname = "192.168.1.X"
plink.exe -ssh -l $username -pw $password $hostname -t "cslogin"
```

See [Using the command-line connection tool Plink](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html).

Comment: Sorry about that, was trying to get this to work with both SSH module and plink and forget to remove the Import-Module SSH-Sessions
code.

Comment: Also tried with the plink -t parameter and  got this ->bash: cslogin: command not found

Comment: If you login with SSH terminal client (e.g. PuTTY), can you execute the `cslogin`?

Comment: Yes, I can, whether I use putty, plink or SSH module I still get the "SEC054 A device has connected to, or disconnected from, a pseudo tty without authenticating" message. I can get pass the message by hiting the enter key

Comment: I was thinking as a possible solution, if I can search the output for the message and then break to the next line of code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you're not actually using ssh.net here. Sure, you import the module but instead of using the `New-SSHSession` or `Invoke-SSHCommand` cmdlets you then run plink to connect and run `cslogin`. I confess I've not heard of that Linux command but bear in mind that plink expects to connect via SSH, execute a command and disconnect - so you won't get an interactive prompt.

You can either have plink run a script on the Linux server, or using the `-m` switch get plink to read a list of commands drone a file.

Alternatively you can setup a putty saved session then run plink to get interactive session but you might get some oddities in the powershell command window when it tries to interpret the output from plink.

for more info see [this link](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter7.html%23plink-usage-interactive)